# Substraction of two columns

Tags: r

I really can't understand when I am able to use a different functions. I always have the same problem... "it's not vaild for atomic vectors, dataframes, matrices... etc.

Can someone explain me how I can substract two columns of matrix or data.frame or anything...

That's my data:

```
id  cond    S1.pre  S2.pre  S1.post S2.post V1.pre  V2.pre  V1.post V2.post
  1 aer       21    31        25    35         7     1        19     4
  2 aer       15    26        21    29        13    11        16    14
  3 aer       18    27        23    31         8     2         3     3
  4 aer       17    31        18    39        13    11        15    14
  5 aer       15    26        16    29        26    15        32    20
```

I want to substract the column S1.post - S1.pre.

That's what I tried:

```
> diff <- data[,"S1.post"] - data[,"S1.pre"]
Error in data[, "S1.post"] - data[, "S1.pre"] : 
non-numeric argument to binary operator
> diff <- data$S1.post - data$S1.pre
Error in data$S1.post : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Classes:

```
> class("S1.pre")
[1] "character"

> class("data")
[1] "character"
```

Comment: I can't replicate your problem. `data[,"S1.post"] - data[,"S1.pre"] [1] 4 6 5 1 1`. Also, use `class(data)` and not `class("data")`.`"data"` is `character` but `data` is (or should be) a `data.frame`

Comment: I used "data <- read.delim("Stats1.13.HW.03.txt")" to read a txt file.

Comment: Try converting the appropriate columns to integer and try again. You can use this if you want... `data2 <- do.call( data.frame , c(data[,1:2] , lapply( data[,-c(1:2)] , as.integer ) ) )`. You'll get a new data.frame `data2` which you can do `data2[,"S1.post"] - data2[,"S1.pre"]` on.

Comment: @ShaxiLiver I am assuming your problem is because R automatically thought your columns were factor variables. Try `sapply( data , class )`. If it's not `numeric` or `integer` for the columns you are interested in, then `-` won't work.

Comment: Also, you could use `stringsAsFactors = F` when you call `read.delim` but I don't know if this is an acceptable argument to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I *think* that you have possibly two problems here:

First either you *think* you have a `data.frame` when in fact you have a matrix, or your data was at some point a matrix and is now a `data.frame` so all expected numeric values got converted to character and then got converted to `factor` on the way back to a data.frame.

If your data is a matrix, `$` is not defined for accessing `matrices` hence the `"$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors"` error. Second, if you have a matrix, and all data in a `matrix` *must be of the same type*, all your columns are of type `character`.

If you type `class( data )` I would expect it will return `"matrix"`.

I would convert to a data.frame and then convert the appropriate columns to `integer` for further use...

```
data <- as.data.frame( data )

data2 <- do.call( data.frame , c(data[,1:2] , lapply( data[,-c(1:2)] , as.integer ) ) )
```

Then hopefully you will see...

```
sapply( data2 , class )
#       id      cond    S1.pre    S2.pre   S1.post   S2.post    V1.pre    V2.pre  V1.post   V2.post 
# "factor"  "factor" "integer" "integer" "integer" "integer" "integer" "integer" "integer" "integer"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try converting your columns to "numeric" before subtracting, with the function `as.numeric`

```
data$S1.pre <- as.numeric(data$S1.pre)
```